# SQL - Selecting rows within a date range?

Tags: sql, date, timestamp, presto

I am trying to select all rows that are within a date range including the start and end day -

for example

```
Select *
from table
where timestamp between 2019-03-01 and 2019-03-08
```

I want all rows that are on 2019-03-01 and 2019-03-08 and all rows between the two dates as well

Thanks

Comment: the variables must be in single quotes and what type of data is your timestamp column?

Comment: thanks, it is a timestamp column i usually discern with date

Comment: what do you mean by ` all rows between the two dates as well` is it should be order by timestamp/??? clear it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use date()  for timestamp and proper quote around the date value

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_recordings 
WHERE date(timestamp)  
          between  str_to_date('2019-03-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
              and   str_to_date('2019-03-08', '%Y-%m-%d');
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_recordings 
WHERE date(timestamp) between '2019-03-01'  and   '2019-03-08';
```

Comment: if I use the latter of just between, will it also include rows on the outer bound dates such as 3-1 and 3-8 as well? @scaisEdge

Comment: `BETWEEN` is always inclusive. That means it will include until `2019-03-08 00:00:00.000`.